# Convertir una cantidad en dolares a ethereum

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, api

tengo que crear un sistema en una pagina para pagar en crypto moneda partiendo de una cantidad en dolares, por ejemplo: el usuario tiene en el carrito 3 productos que en total hacen 59.00$, pues si quiere pagar en ETH, pues se le tiene que mostrar cuanto equivale en ETH para asi pagar

la idea que tuve al principio fue usar API que me de el precio actual del ETH y usando la regla de 3 convertir el valor en dolares a su equivalente a ETH, pero el resultado es algo impredecible a veces se excede un cero y otra veces le falta un cero.

Me gustaria saber si alguien tiene alguna idea de como realizarlo de forma correcta, por aqui abajo dejare el script que estoy usando por si quieren saber como lo hice hasta ahora

```
/////////////////////////////////////////
    /// MetaMask payment script ////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    if (window.ethereum) {
        ethereumOn.value = true;
    }else {
        ethereumOn.value = false;
    }

    const ethereum = window.ethereum;
    let account = null;
    let totalEther = 0;

    fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=ethereum&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false')
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json()
            }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            totalEther = totalPrice / data[0].current_price;
            totalEther = totalEther.toString();
            totalEther = totalEther.replace(/[.]/g, '');
            console.log(totalEther)

        });
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podrias agregar ejemplos? el codigo parece correcto...

Comment: No siempre la petición a la API se resuelve y tu código debe contemplar esos casos. Agrega un `.catch` al final de todos tus `.then` para que contemples el caso en que la petición falle. Ahí puedes poner lo que quieres hacer para que no se quede en 0. Por lo demás, tu código parece funcionar bien, es más un error que ocurre cuando falla la petición que no tienes contemplado.